# Runtime Error: Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, excel

I receive the error: Method or data member not found at line
.SendKeys ("")

I am scraping from a screen and this the command I send to place the cursor in the right place before sending the command in the next line to change screens. I do not understand why I am receiving this error.

```
Sub RLinfo()

    Dim sys
    Dim sess
    Dim chan
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim linecount As Long
    ' RL Information xxxx

    Set Host = CreateObject("BZWh.WhllObj")
    Host.OpenSession 0, 1, "xxxx.zmd", 30, 1
    Set sess = Host.ActiveSession
    Set chan = sess.Screen
    Set ws = Worksheets("Information")
    With ws
    x = 14
    y = 19

    Set OUTPUTSHEET = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Information")

    With chan



    linecount = 2
        Do While OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 30) = "Zip"
            RL = Format(OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 1), "000000000")

            .SendKeys ("<Home>")
            .SendKeys ("/for x203<Enter>")
            .waithostquiet (10)
            .SendKeys (RL & "<Enter>")
            .waithostquiet (10)
        If Trim(.getstring(14, 2, 30)) = "RL WAS NOT FOUND" Then
            OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 20) = "RL No Longer In X203"
            GoTo Found
        Else
        End If
            OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 17) = Trim(.getstring(11, 6, 6))
            OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 18) = Trim(.getstring(8, 27, 12))
            OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 19) = Trim(.getstring(9, 27, 12))
            OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 20) = Trim(.getstring(5, 41, 26))

        For x = 14 To 20
            If Trim(.getstring(x, 2, 7)) = "NUM" Then
           OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 21) = Trim(.getstring(x, 11, 11))
           GoTo Found
           Else
            End If
        Next x

         If Trim(.getstring(23, 72, 6)) = "N MORE" Then
         .SendKeys ("<PA1>")
         .waithostquiet (10)
         For y = 19 To 22
            If Trim(.getstring(y, 2, 7)) = "NUM" Then
           OUTPUTSHEET.Cells(linecount, 21) = Trim(.getstring(y, 11, 11))
           GoTo Found
           Else
            End If
        Next y
        Else
        End If
    Found:
            linecount = linecount + 1
       Loop
        End With
        End With
    ws.Cells(2, 31) = linecount
    endM:
End Sub
```

Comment: I think `SendKeys` is a member of the `Application` object, not a `Screen` object

Comment: @CallumDA So do I change Set chan = sess.Screen to Set chan = sess.Application

Comment: Remove the `.` from `.SendKeys`. Also `SendKeys` are highly unreliable. Consider using `FindWindow` and `SendMessage` Api in lieu of that

Comment: @Siddharth Rout When I remove the . and just use SendKeys then the .waithostquiet (10) does not work and there is no delay for the host screen to respond. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Check [**`this`**](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problem was that I was not disconnecting from the Host when I moved between modules. At the start of each module I was reconnecting to the Host even though I had not disconnected in the previous module and this caused the run time error.